# flutter_webview_plugin_ios_android 0.3.12 onStateChanged is not getting triggered in release mode

Tags: flutter, webview

I am new to flutter and I am using flutter_webview_plugin_ios_android 0.3.12 package. I just want to hide a button in webview. I have a stateful widget and in init method I have implemented the following code:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged
    .listen((WebViewStateChanged viewState) async {
  print('------------------------here');
  print(viewState.type);
  print(WebViewState.finishLoad);
  if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
    print('working 3----------');
    await flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
        "document.getElementById('btnBack').style.display = 'none';");
  }
});
```

It is working as expected in local.. But in apk and release mode, the onStateChanged is not getting triggered. Even the print statement is not getting executed!

I have tried changing FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin(); to final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin(); but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin. This plugin has a method called onUrlChange and onPageFinished that is invoked on when url for the webview is changed and fully loaded. So in this method I checked for the url match and using controller.runJavaScript() evaluated the javascript for hiding the button.

Works smooth..!!